# Find all polynomials $P(x)$ satisfying this functional equation

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

> Find all polynomials $P(x)$ which have the property
>   $$P[F(x)]=F[P(x)], \quad P(0) = 0$$
>   where $F(x)$ is  a given function with the property $F(x)>x$ for all $x\geq 0$.

This is an exercise from my homework. I would appreciate any kind explanations. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @MFG I'm not sure what you started a bounty, Landscape's answer seems good (unless of course, you started the bounty before the answer was posted, which seems unlikely to me given the timestamp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$ for every $n\ge 0$. Since $F(x)>x$ for every $x\ge 0$, $x_{n+1}>x_n$ for every $n\ge 0$. Note that $P(x_0)=x_0$ and 
$$P(x_{n+1})=P(F(x_n))=F(P(x_n)),\quad\forall n\ge 0.$$
Then by induction, it is easy to see that
$$P(x_n)=x_n,\quad\forall n\ge 0.\tag{1}$$
$(1)$ implies that the polynomial $P(x)-x$ has infinitely many roots, i.e. $P(x)\equiv x$.